# Issue Executing JMP Application

Tags: perl, winapi, ole

I plan to automatically call the JMP application by using the script below, but when I run it, it goes straight to printing hello word, the script initializes and completes, but it doesn't execute the JMP application. It skips it, with no result being saved. Why?

```
#! C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin
#!/usr/bin/perl   -w
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;

print "hello word";

use Win32::OLE;
print "Script Initializing", "\n";

my $jmp = Win32::OLE->new('JMP.Application');

$jmp->{Visible} = 1;

$jmp->RunJSLFile("Z:\\trybar.jsl");

print "Done\n";

$jmp->Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear, and there are several potential reasons for your problem. But these  points may help

- A shebang line is useless on Windows, so it is best to remove it
- Always `use warnings` instead of `-w` on the shebang line

This variation on your own code will work fine, but remember that you will get errors if there are problems with the contents of `trybar.jsl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;

print "Script initialising\n";

my $jmp = Win32::OLE->new('JMP.Application');

$jmp->{Visible} = 1;
$jmp->RunJSLFile('Z:\trybar.jsl');

print "Done\n";

$jmp->Quit;
```